# How can I find matching data in another worksheet and return boolean value in a specific cell in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook with 2 worksheets. "Invoice" and "Products".

In "Invoice" I have several columns, `A("ID")`, `B("DESIGN")` which is selected list from Products sheet and `C("QTE")`...etc. It looks like this:

```
 A    B    C    D ...
---------------------
100   AR
110   BR
120   CR
130   DR
```

In "Products" I have other columns, `A("ID")` and `B("DESIGN")`, `C("NAME")`, `D("TYPE")`. It looks like this:

```
 A    B     C      D    
----------------------
10    AR   NAME1   TY1
20    BR   NAME2   TY2
30    CR   NAME3   TY2
40    DR   NAME4   TY1
```

So, when I select `DESIGN` In "Invoice" sheet (column B), I need to check and return true/false in a specific cell IF the type of the `DESIGN` selected is `TY1`

Examples:

- In Invoice sheet: IF i select `AR` as `DESIGN` i want a specific cell return true (because of `AR` is of `TYPE=TY1`)
- In Invoice sheet: IF i select `BR` as `DESIGN` i want a specific cell return false(because of `BR` is of `TYPE!=TY1`)

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything/are you stuck at a specific point? If not, split the problem up and solve it one by one. Your question title itself already kinda does that. "find matching data", "access different worksheets", "set cell value" etc.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to do this.  Take a look at the various Excel lookup functions.

Answer (score 0):

This may work.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

        Dim sWhatToLook As String
        Dim rng1 As Range
        Dim strSearch As String

        If Target.Column = 2 Then 'for the code to execute clicking on column B only
            sWhatToLook = Target.Value
            Set rng1 = Worksheets("Products").Range("A2:D1000").Find(sWhatToLook, , xlValues, xlWhole) 'Set range (A2:D1000) as needed
            If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
                If (rng1.Offset(0, 2).Value = "TY1") Then
                    Worksheets("Invoice").Cells(Target.Row, 5) = True
                Else
                    Worksheets("Invoice").Cells(Target.Row, 5) = False
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox sWhatToLook & " not found"
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```